# UINavigationBar: Set colors in subclass

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have the following subclass:

```
class GeneralNavigationBar: UINavigationBar {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.barTintColor = UIColor(rgb: 0x2A5298) //Extension that converts hex to color
        self.tintColor = UIColor.white
    }
}
```

I want the title of the bar to be white. When I apply this class to a NavigationBar in the storyboard, the background gets blue (hex, as he is supposed to), but the title remains black.

It's strange, since you can alter the color of the bar in the ViewController it appears in:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor   = UIColor(red: 204/255, green: 47/255, blue: 40/255, alpha: 1.0)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

This works.

Answer (score 0):

Try **appearance**,see how..

```
var navbarappearace = UINavigationBar.appearance()
navbarappearace.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 204/255, green: 47/255, blue: 40/255, alpha: 1.0)
navbarappearace.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

Put the above code in **AppDelegate**, it should affect the whole project.

Cheers.